# Error when using 'which' to find position in a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, integrate, envelope

**Update 2.0: Now with data such that the errors should be reproducible:**

Data for the different functions:

```
z <- seq(0,2,length=1000)
t <- grid <- c(0.1,0.55,0.9)
parA <- c(0.21,-0.93)
parB <- c(0.21,1.008)
p <- c(1,2,1,2)

## for plotting ##

f_func <- function(x) exp(-x^3+x)
envARS1 <- function(x){ exp(parA[1]*x+parB[1])}
envARS2 <- function(x){ exp(parA[2]*x+parB[2])}
plot(x=z,y=envARS1(z), type = "l", col = "blue", ylim = c(0,2), xlim = c(0,2))
lines(x=z,y=envARS2(z), type = "l", col = "red")
lines(x = z,(f_func(z)), type = "l", col = "black")
```

I'm trying to implement an Adaptive rejection sampler using a derivative-free approach. Along the way of this implementation, I have to implement a dynamic envelope function, which is able to adjust depending on the values/number of some Zt's.

I have accomplished to write a dynamic envelope function which seems to work fine but when I try to integrate the envelope, with the final aim of drawing from this envelope, I get errors.

```
DynamicEnv <- function(x){
exp(parA[p[max(which(x>=grid))]]*x+
parB[p[max(which(x>=grid))]])
}
```

The envelope function is a exponential linear line and the parameters a and b depends on where the x, it's input, is located relatively to the Zt's.
The variable 'grid' contains the Zt's and is therefore a vector, p is a dynamic position variable, which essentially tells the function which parameters to use.

So the first problem I had was that, when I gave my dynamic envelope a vector as input, I get troubles with the 'which' function which only can handle numeric values as far as I understand.

**Updated with the error I receive from 'which'**

I get the below error with which:

```
Error in which(x > grid) : 
dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [1000]
```

Which I believe occurs because 'which' tries to compare both vectors to each other, and not the n'th element in x with the entire vector of grid.

Then I try to incorporate a loop, to loop over all the values in the x-vector, and return a vector with the output values, but then I got the error message 'non-finite function values' when I tried to integrate my dynamic envelope.

The dynamic envelope with a loop inside is;

```
DynamicEnv1 <- function(x){

Draws <- matrix(0,length(x),1)

for (i in 1:length(x)) Draws[i,1] <- 
exp(parA[p[max(which(x[i]>=grid))]]*x[i] + parB[p[max(which(x[i]>=grid))]])

return(Draws)
}
```

I have written this 'static' envelope function, which works fine with respect to making draws from it (thereby integrate).

```
envARSup <- function(x){ (ifelse((x <= t[1] | t[2] < x & x <= t[3]), 
exp(parA[1]*x+parB[1]),exp(parA[2]*x+parB[2])))*1*(x>0)}
```

Here the t's are the Zt's mentioned above. The idea of the dynamic envelope should be clear from this function, since they ideally should be able to return the same for the same grid (Zt's/t's). 
The above function checks which interval the value of x belongs to, and based on the interval it uses a specific exponential linear line.

I would really appreciate if someone could suggest an alternative to the 'which' function, in order to locate a position in a vector or help me understand why I get the error message with the loop-based dynamic envelope.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you show the error you are getting with `which`, and try to make your example a bit more minimal - see [mcve].

Comment: @dash2 I have updated my question with the error. 
I don't know how to make my question more minimal without the reader loosing any insight.

Comment: Could you make it complete? At the moment nobody can run your code since we don't know what data you are using when you call these functions.

Comment: @dash2 Hi Dash
All relevant data should be included now.
I should of cause have thought of that